# Creating a procedure inside a query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, grafana

I'm trying to implement a **MySQL procedure** (with if/else statements) inside a Granada query. The only issue is it won't let me create my procedure and call it from the same query...

## ERROR

`db query error: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL tester(true)' at line 44`

I'm confident the issue isn't with my syntax, but here's how the query looks:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE tester(
  IN is_empty BOOLEAN
)
BEGIN
    IF(is_empty) THEN

        SELECT 
        ...
        from $dbName.table1
        where KernelName IN ($KernelNameFilter) AND `gpu-id` in ($gpuFilter) AND `Index` in ($DispatchIDFilter) 

        union SELECT
        ...
        from $dbName.table1
        where KernelName IN ($KernelNameFilter) AND `gpu-id` in ($gpuFilter) AND `Index` in ($DispatchIDFilter) 

    ELSE

        SELECT
        ...
        from $dbName.table1
        where KernelName IN ($KernelNameFilter) AND `gpu-id` in ($gpuFilter) AND `Index` in ($DispatchIDFilter);

    END IF;
END;

CALL tester(true);
```

They seem to work on their own, but I have no idea why Grafana doesn't like this syntax. Any ideas?

**NOTE:**
*Yes, it is necessary for me to create the procedure in Grafana query b/c I need to reference local Grafana variables (i.e. $KernelNameFilter, $gpuFilter, ...)*

Comment: I suspect the cause of the problem you see is that `mysqli` and `PDO` don't automatically support multiple queries. In any case, creating the procedure every time you want to run it is redundant. You should create the procedure once (using an external tool like MySQL Workbench if necessary) and then just call it. If you need local variables pass them in as parameters in your `CALL`.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you can't create procedure and call the procedure in a single call to the query interface. Most query interfaces do not support multi-query.

Even if the query interface supports multi-query, you can't use it to define a stored routine. Multi-query interfaces assume semicolon terminates the statement, so the first semicolon inside the body of your procedure would terminate the whole CREATE PROCEDURE statement. That's not what you want.

The MySQL client solves this by requiring you to change the statement terminator to something that doesn't appear in the body of the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html for details.

> I need to reference local Grafana variables (i.e. $KernelNameFilter, $gpuFilter, ...)

You should make a procedure that takes your Grafana variables as parameters, and *uses* them in the queries within the procedure body — not create a brand new procedure each time you need to run the procedure.